# How much padding material is added to each CSS font weight attribute

Tags: css, font-face

I realise every font is different but how is the font-weight calculated. I'm trying to replicate the exact font-weight on an svg typeface.

Comment: Depends on the font. Most fonts have entirely separate typefaces for 400 and 700 weight.

Comment: even depends on browsers, if they have to calculate(you dont have separate font faces for each weight), result may vary acros browsers